# Datatables.Net row cilck event not working after row 10

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to open a modal to be used as an edit screen based on the click of a table row. However, this is only working on the first 10 rows of the table.

the code im using to get the row data is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("tr").click(function () {
    //alert($(this.id).selector);
    $("#updateCase").modal();
  });
});
```

the table is being build up like this but with 538 rows

```
<table id='tblProcessing' class='table table-striped table-hover table-border'>
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th class='centre RequestId' hidden>RequestId</th>
  <th class='centre CMCReference'>CMC Reference</th>
  <th class='centre FirstCustomerName'>First Customer Name</th>
  <th class='centre FirstCustomerDOB'>First Customer DOB</th>
  <th class='centre SecondCustomerName'>Second Customer Name</th>
  <th class='centre SecondCustomerDOB'>Second Customer DOB</th>
  <th class='centre CustomerPostcode'>Customer Postcode</th>
  <th class='centre BusinessArea'>Business Area</th>
  <th class='centre AccountType'>Account Type</th>
  <th class='centre AccountOrCardNumber'>Account Or Card Number</th>
  <th class='centre LOAOutcome'>LOA Outcome</th>
  <th class='centre Outcome'>Outcome</th>
  <th class='centre Response'>Response</th>
  <th class='centre Complete'>Complete</th>
  <th class='centre Edit'>Edit</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tfoot class='foot'>
  <tr>
  <th>RequestId</th>
  <th>CMC Reference</th>
  <th>First Customer Name</th>
  <th>First Customer DOB</th>
  <th>Second Customer Name</th>
  <th>Second Customer DOB</th>
  <th>Customer Postcode</th>
  <th>Business Area</th>
  <th>Account Type</th>
  <th>Account Or Card Number</th>
  <th>LOA Outcome</th>
  <th>Outcome</th>
  <th>Response</th>
  <th>Complete</th>
  <th>Edit</th>
 </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
  <tr id='2211'>
    <td class='centre RequestId' hidden>xxxx</td>
    <td class='centre CMCReference'>xxxxx</td>
    <td class='centre FirstCustomerName'>Susan Seymour</td>
    <td class='centre FirstCustomerDOB'>08/10/1981 </td>
    <td class='centre SecondCustomerName'></td>
    <td class='centre SecondCustomerDOB'></td>
    <td class='centre CustomerPostcode'>PE4 XXX</td>
    <td class='centre BusinessArea'></td>
    <td class='centre AccountType'>Mortgage</td>
    <td class='centre AccountOrCardNumber'>xxxxxxxx</td>
    <td class='centre LOAOutcome'>Not Seen</td>
    <td class='centre Outcome'></td>
    <td class='centre Response'></td>
    <td class='centre Complete'>True</td>
    <td class='centre Edit'><span class='btn><i id='xxxx' class='fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x edit' aria-hidden='true'></i></span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

and I am calling it using `$('#tblProcessing' ').DataTable();`

What confuses me is that the first 10 rows are clickable but nothing thereafter.

Any and all help appreciated.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the next page is dynamically created by the DataTable plugin, so you need to use a delegated event handler:

```
$('#tblProcessing').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    //alert($(this.id).selector);
    $("#updateCase").modal();
});
```

Comment: Perfect! that works thank you. I cant accept the answer for another 11 minutes, but will do as soon as I can.